# Copy between storage accounts in same region

Tags: azure-storage, azure-blob-storage, azcopy

I have tried copying a 1TB disks between storage accounts in the same Azure region using AzCopy and Azure Storage Explorer. AzCopy was slower than Explorer. It took 5 hours and 30 minutes every time.

I have already tried the /SynCopy option for AzCopy in a VM in the same region, but it was still slower.

My question is: can it be done any faster?

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think the `/SynCopy` option or others for `AzCopy` will make faster on VM, such as the document has point out the reason as below.

> [**Synchronously copy blobs from one storage account to another**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/common/storage-use-azcopy?toc=%2Fazure%2Fstorage%2Fblobs%2Ftoc.json#synchronously-copy-blobs-from-one-storage-account-to-another)
>
> AzCopy by default copies data between two storage endpoints asynchronously. Therefore, the copy operation runs in the background ***using spare bandwidth capacity*** that has no SLA in terms of how fast a blob is copied, and AzCopy periodically checks the copy status until the copying is completed or failed.
>
> The /SyncCopy option ensures that the copy operation ***gets consistent speed***. AzCopy performs the synchronous copy by downloading the blobs to copy from the specified source to local memory, and then uploading them to the Blob storage destination.

Here just recommend other solutions for your scenario, except using AzCopy or Azure Storage Explorer in a VM to copy a blob between storage accounts in the same region, there are two ways to do the same faster possiblely.

1. Recommended to create Azure Data Factory in the same region without a VM to copy data, please refer to the offical tutorial [`Quickstart: Use the Copy Data tool to copy data`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/quickstart-create-data-factory-copy-data-tool) to know how to get started. It's an alone service and will take full advantage of network bandwidth in cloud to transfer data, not like Azure VM has some limits.
2. There is a highly concurrent data transfer tool for Azure Blob Storage named [`Azure/blobporter`](https://github.com/Azure/blobporter) which you can try to run on VM, but I don't think it will be faster than Azure Data Factory.

Comment: Thank you for the reply. I will look into those solutions.They are new for me.

Comment: It took time but I just copied the VHD using Azure Storage Explorer. Thanks for your response